# Approval required from organisation 3 to add assets by org1 ( asset data should be checked by ORG3 whether data is valid)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

i have a network configuration containing three Organisations (ORG1 & ORG2 & ORG 3 ) having two peers each , Now only ORG1 has to add the assets to ledger ( this is achieved ) and org2 has to only view the assets added by ORG1 ( this is achieved ) Now the third condition is ORG3 has to check the data added by org1 and if approved the asset should be added else it shouldn't how to achieve this

Comment: not enough info - why don't you post in your questions, the existing ACL rules / logic you're using - does it mean you notify the org 3 participant via a client application  to do an Approval - which then runs a transaction that 'approves' the asset creation? Org 2 would only see approved assets

Comment: we need not notify the org3 participant via a client app just we need to perform  some kind of data validation on the assets added by org1 and only approved assets should be viewed by org2

Comment: namespace test
// The simplest asset possible
participant SampleParticipant identified by id {
  o String id
  o String name
}
asset SampleAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  o String policy 
} this is the model file